# c# , How to do search with query

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to do it search . I used c# connect with MySQL database. And when will create the Entity Relation Diagram between tables. I want to used query such as to find with mobile of customer that this specific assignment belong to specific customer.

I try this.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
connection.Open();

try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();


    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM assignments  WHERE assignments.Customer_ID = customers.Customer_ID;
    //assignments and customers are tables
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView5.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;


}
catch (Exception)
{

    //throw;

    MessageBox.Show("Please complete correct the fields");
}

finally
{

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {

        connection.Clone();

    }
}
```

Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be wrong. You need to join the table correctly like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM assignments 
       inner join Customers on assignments.Customer_ID = customers.Customer_ID";
```

Comment: Yes , but  when i want to find with mobile of customer ? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
String mobile = "";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mySqlConn)) {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string queryString = "SELECT mobile FROM assignments 
       inner join Customers on assignments.Customer_ID = customers.Customer_ID";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn);
                using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        mobile = rdr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {  }
        }
```